# Clock Pulse from Audio Signal (Laptop Headphone Jack)

Tags: transistors, ttl

Been fiddling with some circuits on breadboard to get a stable clock pulse from an audio signal via a laptops headphone jack.

Reason 1: Other precision sig gennies are out of the budget right now
Reason 2: Got this laptop with all the sig gen software but no way to output it as a 5V clock source.

Frequency range: 10hz to 3000hz.

Tried various voltage amplifier configurations with a single transistor (2N3904) approach. So far none of them are working. Output should be a flashing LED.

How can I get TTL signals from my sound card?

Comment: Do you have a 5V power supply?

Comment: Tell us more about what you've tried and why it didn't meet your requirements.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question or questions? I see several statements - you're not really asking anything.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a TTL clock signal, this is easy. The best choice would be to be a comparator IC. The output is typically open collector. Pull it up to 5V. Ground the inverting pin, and run your sound card signal into the non-inverting pin. Just leave the signal as a sine, the output will be square and 50% duty cycle.

My next choice would be to set an op amp up as a comparator, and power it off 5V single supply. You'll want to use a CMOS op amp for this.

Using your transistor would take a little work, but it wouldn't be my first choice of component for this task.

Answer (score 0):

A simple analog to logic converter uses the HC04 buffered inverter. (hex inverter CMOS)

You can choose gain like Op Amp R ratio and AC couple to allow self-bias.

e.g. C1= 0.1uF R1= 10K  R2=1M  Gain=100
Vcc can match your logic voltage level. Input voltage range from 0.1 to 3V will produce good results. Add de-coupling cap close to chip and use a /2 flip flip to get perfect square wave's if needed.

Then use Audacity application to generate sweep signals linear or log and define output as 1V.

[image]